# TYPO3 - Create User programmatically

Tags: php, typo3

Is it possible to create or delete a User programmatically (**without SQL**) in a typo3 extension?

Comment: What do you mean without SQL? TYPO3 users are stored in database, so to create them or delete them you need at the end an SQL command.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to use a TYPO3 Function to add a User? (TYPO3 API?)

Comment: One question for me is "why?" ... because I don't think, that TYPO3 will change the db-structure of fe_users or be_users ... otherwise a lot (and I really mean a lot) extensions will break.

Answer (score 2):

To CRUD frontend users (fe_users) there already is a Repository and a Model available which you might use in your own Extbase extension. Below...

typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Domain

you can find the Model and Repository classes.

Answer (score 1):

some code examples:

```
function createUser() {
    // TypoScript Template mit userid anlegen
    // Neue Seite anlegen
    $tmpId = 'NEWuser478d8d';
    $data['be_users'][$tmpId] = array(
        'username' => $this->email,
        'password' => $this->password,
        'admin' => 0,
        'pid' => 0,
        'usergroup' => $this->usergroup,
        'lang' => 'de',
        'email' => $this->email,
        'db_mountpoints' => '',
        'realName' => $this->realName,
        'file_mountpoints' => '',
        'fileoper_perms' => (int)$this->conf['fileoper_perms'],
        'options' => '2', // mount from group: filemount, aber nicht dbmount
        'db_mountpoints' => $this->dbMountPage,
        'file_mountpoints' => $this->conf['file_mountpoints'],
        'workspace_perms' => 0,
        'workspace_id' => 0,
        'workspace_preview' => 0
    );
    $this->debug($data, 'beuser');
    $this->tce->start($data,array());
    $this->tce->process_datamap();
    $this->userid =  $this->tce->substNEWwithIDs[$tmpId];
    // t3lib_div::debug('Neue Userid:'.$this->userid);
    return true;
}
```

afair you need an be-user which is active, so create one:

```
/**
 *  Creates a Be-User
 *
 *  @return     void
 */
function setBeUser() {
    global $BE_USER;
    unset($BE_USER);
    $BE_USER        = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_beUserAuth');
    $BE_USER->OS    = TYPO3_OS;
    $BE_USER->setBeUserByUid($this->conf['setBeUserByUid']);
    $BE_USER->fetchGroupData();
    $BE_USER->backendSetUC();

    $GLOBALS['BE_USER'] = $BE_USER;

    $GLOBALS['LANG'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('language');
    $GLOBALS['LANG']->init($BE_USER->uc['lang']);

    return $BE_USER;
}
```

init tce:

```
$this->tce = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_TCEmain');
$this->tce->BE_USER = $this->setBeUser();
$this->tce->stripslashes_values = 0;
$this->createUser();
```

Comment: pa-ddy, are we here talking about a backend or frontend user?

Comment: $data['be_users'] means "Backend User" $data['fe_users'] would mean Frontend user - but check fields then